# Obtaining Mouse Coordinates from Kinect video image

Tags: wpf, mouse, kinect

I'm learning Kinect and C#, so I'm having some problems with my new project. I want to get the distance from a certain object to the Kinect. I'm thinking of using solids to make it simple. So the idea would be: use the mouse to select a point from the kinect's image, obtain my x and y coordinates. Then with the coordinates I think I can get the distance.

I'm using a Kinect XBOX360 and WPF in C#.

Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you watch this sessions on Channel 9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-055 where he builds exactly what you describe.

You can downloads his sample code here: 
http://robrelyea.com/demos/KinectMagicMirror/

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying the Kinect video in a WPF image then you can hook on to the images mouse move event (or mouse down event) and obtain the cursor location relative to the image with the following.

```
    void image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseLocation = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
    }
```

0,0 in mouseLocation would be the top left of the kinect picture.

Comment: How can I obtain the x value from the "mouselocation"? I want to click on the edges of a solid and also obtain the distance between those edges.